# Add dynamic parameters to API using retrofit in KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

How to pass same parameter multiple times to API call using retrofit.
Code to API

```
    interface RvStageMaterialApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @PUT("/api/Reservation/StageMaterial")
    suspend fun rvIssueMaterialApi(
        @Field("StockAndLocationList") stockAndLocationList: String,
    ): RvStageMaterialsResponse
}
```

Post man request and response added example : https://api.example.com/tasks?id=123&id=124&id=125
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried @part and it worked as expected

```
 interface RvStageMaterialApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @PUT("/api/Reservation/StageMaterial")
    suspend fun rvIssueMaterialApi(
        @Part("StockAndLocationList") stockAndLocationList: String,
    ): RvStageMaterialsResponse
}
```